# My code tells me there is a syntax error but when I execute in terminal, my code works

Tags: python, pandas, terminal

I am starting to learn python, so you all will have to forgive the question. I am coding python using vscode on a mac mini m2 (not sure if that even matters, just painting a picture)

I have the following code

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('expense.csv')
test = data['Amount']

test
```

and I am getting the following error when I execute my code:

```
>>> /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/myname/Documents/Test python project/expense.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/myname/Documents/Test python project/expense.py"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

how can I fix this?

The weird part is that if I delete

```py
test = data['Amount']

test
```

of my code and try running it still give me the same exact error, but If I type data on my terminal then the table does come up!

Very confused on why this is happening. Could I get help please?

Comment: What is the `>>>` prompt you show? That looks like you are already executing python. It looks like you should `exit()` to the command line and try again.

Comment: Code is correct. You may be missing a package that wasn't installed with pandas.